# how many triples of real numbers $(a,b,c)$ are there such that a,b,c are the roots of the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, cubics

How many triples of real numbers $(a,b,c)$ are there such that $a,b,c$ are the roots of the equation ??

$$x^3 +ax^2+bx+c=0$$

Answer (score 1):

So you want to know how many $a, b, c$ satisfy $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ which is equivalent to

$-abc=c,ab+bc+ac=b,a+b+c=-a$

Answer (score 1):

Solving Jeff's equations:
$$ \eqalign{a&= 0,b=0,c=0\cr
            a&=1, b=-2, c=0\cr
            a&=1, b=-1, c=1\cr
            a = b^2/2-1, c=-b^2 - b +2, &\text{ where } b^3 - 2 b+ 2 = 0\cr}$$

Comment: Some people are way too fast...

Comment: It would be helpful to tell the OP *how* you solved it (hopefully something better than "I fed it to Maple" or some other computer algebra system).

Comment: but they r 4 solns,.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint: I confess, I fed it to Maple (in this case, Groebner:-Solve)

Comment: @mathslover: there are indeed four **real** solutions, because the cubic $b^3 - 2b + 2$ has one real root.  There are  complex solutions corresponding to the other roots.